# Get values from variable in other class

Tags: java, object

I'm programming a game Tower Defense. I have 3 classes.

MoveableGameObject, Tower and Monster. I want to send the X coordinates of monster to the Tower class. The method of getX is in the MoveAbleGameObject class. So my tower knows when the monster is in range.

My question is: How do I send the X coordinates from Monster to the Tower class.

Here is my code:

```
public class MonsterDefense  extends MoveableGameObject {

private MoveableGameObject target;
private int[][] tilemap;
private Vissenkom mygame;
private int hp;

public MonsterDefense (Vissenkom spel){
    this.tilemap = tilemap;
    setSprite("leuw");
    setDirectionSpeed(90, 7);
    mygame = spel;
    hp = 100;
    setX(0);
    setY(280);
}

public class Tower extends MoveableGameObject {
    private Vissenkom mygame;
    private int prijs;
    private int damage;
    private int bereik;
}

public Tower(Vissenkom spel) {
    mygame = spel;
    setSprite("toren");
    prijs = 100;
    damage = 50;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I suggest you to have another class called Board, it would contain a list of towers positions and they re ranges. Whenever monster changes position Board notifies the towers with monster in range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just add a Tower method getCoordinates(Monster)?

```
public class Tower extends MoveableGameObject{
   public int getCoordinates(Monster x){
      return x.X;
   }
}
```

I assumed your Monster class has an `int X;` values, which you set with your `setX(0);`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I got the method getX() in the MoveableGameObject class but this should not be a problem. I will try it!

Comment: You made me thinking. Because i got a MonsterController and a TowerController i need to make arraylistst in the monster and tower class.

Those lists wil be static ofcourse :)

After that i can use your getter to tell each tower if the monster is in range. Thank you!